# How to install NITE in Ubuntu10.04?

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, nite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,all. I have a problem about installing nite. it seems that there is no right version for my system on the internet. i am using ubuntu 10.04. If you got it, could you send to me? my email is ntchen86@gmail.com  thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9168/how-to-install-nite-in-ubuntu10.04?/) by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2011-02-22

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on 2011-02-27**:
Hi, mjcarroll. I could not find the version of NITE for Ubuntu10.04. I am looking for it from http://www.primesense.com/, but there are only for Ubuntu10.10.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-02-22**:
Where exactly are you having trouble?  What steps have you done?  Please edit your post to tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 10.04 is our standard development environment.  The ni stack page has a tutorial about how to install.  http://www.ros.org/wiki/ni

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on 2011-02-27**:
HI,Tully. I checked again, but there are no Nite for Ubuntu 10.04.